# Discrepancy in String matching between Teradata and HIVE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, teradata

I am getting into Hive and learning hive. I have customer table in teradata , used sqoop to extract complete table in hive which worked fine.

See below customer table both in Teradata and HIVE.

**In Teradata :**

```
    select TOP 4 id,name,'"'||status||'"' from customer;

    3172460     Customer#003172460  "BUILDING  "     
    3017726     Customer#003017726  "BUILDING  "
    2817987     Customer#002817987  "COMPLETE  "    
    2817984     Customer#002817984  "BUILDING  "
```

**In HIVE :**

```
    select id,name,CONCAT ('"' , status , '"') from customer LIMIT 4;

    3172460     Customer#003172460  "BUILDING  "     
    3017726     Customer#003017726  "BUILDING  "
    2817987     Customer#002817987  "COMPLETE  "    
    2817984     Customer#002817984  "BUILDING  "
```

When I tried to fetch records from table customer with column matching which is of String type. I am getting different result for same query in different environment.

See below query results..

In Teradata :

```
    select TOP 2 id,name,'"'||status||'"' from customer WHERE status = 'BUILDING';

    3172460     Customer#003172460  "BUILDING  "     
    3017726     Customer#003017726  "BUILDING  "
```

In HIVE :

```
    select id,name,CONCAT ('"' , status , '"') from customer WHERE status = 'BUILDING' LIMIT 2;

    **<<No Result>>**
```

It seems that teradata is doing trimming short of thing before actually comparing stating values.  But Hive is matching strings as it is.

Not sure, It is expected behaviour or bug or can be raised as enhancement.

I see below possible solution:
* Convert into like operator expression with wildcard charater before and after

Looking forward for your response on this. How can it be handled/achieved  in hive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rtrim` function, i.e:

```
select id,name,CONCAT ('"' , status , '"') from customer WHERE rtrim(status) = 'BUILDING' LIMIT 2;
```

But question here arise what standard in string comparision Hive uses? According to ANSI/ISO SQL-92 'BUILDING' == 'BUILDING  ', Here is a [link](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626) for an article about it.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  you caught it correctly ....which standard is hive using in string comparision.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question ...got it from hive-user mailing list

Hive is only PRO SQL compliance,

In hive the string comparisons work just like they would work in java

so in hive

```
    "BUILDING" = "BUILDING"
    "BUILDING " != "BUILDING" (extra space added)
```